# Request must have \"Content-Type: application/json\" header error

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, flask

In my flask blog app, I m using AJAX to get users' comments and serialize the data as JSON and post to the app's API. The browser keeps saying i don't have the correct content type header for JSON and the comments aren't posted. It all seems fine to me code wise. I just can't get my head around as to what I missed here. Whatever I submit a comment, I get a line that says:

"message": "Request must have \"Content-Type: application/json\" header"

This is the comments.js file

```js
Comments = window.Comments || {};

(function(exports, $) { /* Template string for rendering success or error messages. */
  var alertMarkup = (
    '<div class="alert alert-{class} alert-dismissable">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
    '<strong>{title}</strong> {body}</div>');

  /* Create an alert element. */
  function makeAlert(alertClass, title, body) {
    var alertCopy = (alertMarkup
                     .replace('{class}', alertClass)
                     .replace('{title}', title)
                     .replace('{body}', body));
    return $(alertCopy);
  }

  /* Retrieve the values from the form fields and return as an object. */
  function getFormData(form) {
    return {
      'name': form.find('input#name').val(),
      'email': form.find('input#email').val(),
      'url': form.find('input#url').val(),
      'body': form.find('textarea#body').val(),
      'entry_id': form.find('input[name=entry_id]').val()
    }
  }

  function bindHandler() {
    /* When the comment form is submitted, serialize the form data as JSON
             and POST it to the API. */
    $('form#comment-form').on('submit', function() {
      var form = $(this);
      var formData = getFormData(form);
      var request = $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
      });
      request.success(function(data) {
        alertDiv = makeAlert('success', 'Success', 'your comment was posted.');
        form.before(alertDiv);
        form[0].reset();
      });
      request.fail(function() {
        alertDiv = makeAlert('danger', 'Error', 'your comment was not posted.');
        form.before(alertDiv);
      });
      return false;
    });
  }

  exports.bindHandler = bindHandler;
})(Comments, jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and in my blog's post detail template, I have also included the comment.js file.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/comments.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        Comments.bindHandler();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I also wrote a helper function in helpers.py that accept the deserialized post data, feed it to the comment form to perform validation before writing the data to the database.

```
def post_preprocessor(data, **kwargs):
    form = CommentForm(data=data)
    if form.validate():
        return form.data
    else:
        raise ProcessingException(
            description='Invalid form submission.', code=400)
```

then in my app.py I have this for the API to work:

```
from helpers import post_preprocessor
api.create_api(
    models.Comment,
    include_columns=['id', 'name', 'url', 'body', 'created_timestamp'],
    include_methods=['avatar'],
    methods=['GET', 'POST'],
    preprocessors={'POST': [post_preprocessor],
    })
```

Comment: did you try removing the `charset=utf-8` and just send `application/json`?

Comment: @pech0rin yea I did. still giving me the same message.

Comment: are you using a Flask extension or something to handle the form? where does `api.create_api` come from?

Comment: @pech0rin i imported the APIManager from flask-restless extension. so in my app.py, before api.create_api(), i have api = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db).